# How casting works in C?

Tags: c, casting

I was solving a [problem](https://www.codechef.com/MARCH221D/problems/SUB_XOR) on leetcode and this was my code.

```c
/*
max int 2147483647 (10^10)
max uint 4294967295 (10^10)
ULONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 (10^20)
LONG_MAX 9223372036854775807 (10^20)
USHRT_MAX 65535, SHRT_MAX 32767
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int t; 
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        int length;
        scanf("%d", &length);
        char string[length];
        scanf("%s", string);
        long int answer = 0;
        int ones = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ones = ones + (string[i] == '1') * (i + 1);
            if (ones & 1) {
                answer = (answer + (long int)pow(2, length - (i + 1))) % 998244353;
            }
        }
        printf("%ld\n", answer);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It is working fine for smaller values (possibly values that int can hold). but when calculating large values it was giving unexpected result

then I thought that might be due to the overflow so I changed variable `int answer` to `long int answer` which I thought will resolve the problem, but it didn't and also broke the code for even smaller values

then I noticed I am using `pow` function which will for sure exceed the limit for high values of length, As `pow` gives double value in return, I was casting it to an `int` with `(int)pow(2, length - (i+1))` before, which I changed to `(long int)pow(2, length - (i+1))`

I was passing these values to test the code.

```
4
16
1111010010111101
2
10
6
101101
4
1111
```

and expected result was

```
49359
3
48
12
```

but i got

```
49359
65535
49152
49152
```

I am getting the expected result when I am using `int answer` and `(int)pow(...)` but if I cast answer or pow to long, I am getting unexpected result. I am not sure if this is due to cast or something else but as far as I noticed it happens only when I am casting these variables into long.

Comment: Don't use `pow()` for powers of 2. Use shifting. For example `1ull << 40`.

Comment: Unrelated: `(string[i]=='1'?1:0)` is an obfuscated way to write `(string[i]=='1')`. The `==` already evaluates to `1` or `0`.

Comment: You didn't update the print formatting. `printf("%d\n", answer);` ==> `printf("%ld\n", answer);`

Comment: Also buffer overflow: `char string[length];` ==> `char string[length+1];`

Comment: What do these comments mean? `(10^10)` Your value for `INT_MAX` is 2*10^9 only.

Comment: @Gerhardh i am sorry i meant 10 * 10 not 10 ^ 10 and that too not exact value just something i can keep myself aware of whenever i am around a digit with a size of 10 or above

Comment: @mch Thanks for the suggestion i will use this next time

Comment: @WeatherVane i actually checked with %ld too but i was too busy changing int to long and vice-versa. I forgot to change that in here. And about buffer overflow you mean a reserved char for `\0`?

Comment: `ones & 1 == 1` is also nonsense, it is the same thing as `ones & 1`. The former merely illustrates that you are unaware of a well-known operator precedence problem in C.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", answer);` No compiler warnings?

Comment: Both clang & gcc give warnings for both of the above mentioned bugs, so it would seem that you are compiling incorrectly with too few warnings enabled. See [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: @Lundin as i said in above comment i was switching int and long frequently, i forgot to add l in printf statement but i checked it with ld and result was same. and this is the very 1st line in my Makefile `CFLAGS=-Wall -g -lm` So i am aware of warnings. I started using C only a month ago So there are things i don't know and i am trying to learn them.

Comment: @Lundin and i was using `(ones & 1) == 1` as i got compiler warnings about that but also forgot to add here as it is old copy of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `while (t--)` will cause unexpected behavior if the value of `t` entered is negative. Use `while (t-- > 0)`
- `char string[length];` does not have enough space for `length` characters and the null terminator. Use `char string[length + 1];`
- `scanf("%s", string);` does not provide any protection against buffer overflow. There is no simple way to tell `scanf()` to read up to a variable number of bytes for `%s`. Since the length can be as large as `100000`, you should probably allocate the array from the heap and read the bits with `getchar()`.
- the code in the loop does not seem to implement a solution for the problem:

  > Given a binary string `S`, she defines the beauty of the string as the bitwise XOR of **decimal representations** of **all substrings** of `S`.

  The instructions are misleading because the result has nothing to do with the decimal representation of anything. But your code does not convert all substrings and only the result should be displayed modulo `998244353`. Applying xor to the modules would produce a different result.
- furthermore there is no need for `pow` to convert a binary representation: you can multiply `res` by 2 and add the value of the next digit in the loop.

To compute the resulting bitstring, consider the bit at offset `i`, starting at the beginning of the string with offset `0`:

- it will be XORed with itself `i` times for substrings with just a prefix removed.
- Then each bit with an index `j` smaller than `i` will be XORed `j` times for each substring with the last `i-j` bits removed.
- XORing `i` times will produce `0` if `i` is odd, hence has the same effect as masking with the opposite of the last bit of `i`.

  You could use 2 nested loops for this:

  ```
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int bit = (string[i] - '0') & ~i;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                bit ^= (string[j] - '0') & ~j;
            }
            answer = (answer * 2 + bit) % 998244353;
        }
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int t, i, j, c;
    int string_size = 0;
    unsigned char *string = NULL;   /* array for the bits */

    /* read the number of test cases */
    if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1)
        return 1;
    while (t-- > 0) {
        int length;
        /* read the length */
        if (scanf("%d", &length) != 1)
            return 1;
        /* discard the rest of the input line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        /* reallocate the string if required */
        if (length > string_size) {
            string_size = length;
            string = realloc(string, string_size);
            if (string == NULL)
                return 1;
        }
        /* read the bits */
        i = 0;
        while (i < length && ((c = getchar()) == '0' || c == '1')) {
            string[i++] = (unsigned char)(c - '0');
        }
        /* discard the rest of the input line */
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
            c = getchar();
        }
        /* compute the answer one bit at a time */
        long int answer = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            /* compute the next bit of the result string */
            int bit = string[i] & ~i;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                bit ^= string[j] & ~j;
            }
            /* compute the answer one bit at a time, reducing modulo 998244353 */
            answer = (answer * 2 + bit) % 998244353;
        }
        printf("%ld\n", answer);
    }
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%.*s", n, dest)` isn't *too* complicated a way to tell `scanf` to read up to a runtime-specified number of bytes into a string.  I don't think it could get much simpler without `scanf` somehow deducing the limit from the destination pointer, which , of course, it has no way of doing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: your suggestion would be nice indeed, but I'm afraid there is no such provision in the C Standard: *After the `%`, the following appear in sequence:
— An optional assignment-suppressing character `*`.
— An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width (in characters).
— An optional length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
— A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.*

Comment: My mistake.  I occasionally forget which format-string features differ between `printf` and `scanf`.  I was in a hurry earlier, and did not verify.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: it is a real shortcoming for `scanf()` to have no provision for a variable limit via `*`, which has a different meaning. Annex K does not address this shortcoming in a viable way, among other problems of its own...

Comment: @chqrlie By looking at your code i realised i am writing really bad code.

Comment: @chqrlie so as i was searching i found one can prevent buffer overflow with `scanf("%[width]s")`. But for a variable like length here how can i set the width. Like i can't use `scanf("%lengths")` and that would be stupid too, but is there a way one can achieve this, just for knowledge.

Comment: @chqrlie i was also thinking, when i am reading a value from stdin like t or l, if it fails the return value is 1. But if i use unique return values, like `if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1) return 123` and `if (scanf("%d", &l)!=1) return 213`, will that be considered a good practise or not. I want to do this because with that i will know exactly where my code failed. It is not useful for this little code but for big projects can one use this?

Comment: @tycoon: thank you for your comment, you can certainly improve your code writing: if you are passionate, honing your skills will be enjoyable and effective. It takes a long time to learn simplicity. Start with code style and consistency, look at open source projects and learn from example.

Comment: @tycoon: regarding `scanf`, you could use a variable limit by composing the format string with `snprintf`: `{ char format[20]; snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%%ds", length); if (scanf(format, string) != 1) return 1; }`  This solution is cumbersome and error prone as the format string is no longer a string constant, preventing compile time validation of the `scanf()` variable argument types.

Comment: @tycoon: returning a specific status code for different error conditions is possible, but a better solution is to output a meaningful error message to `stderr` along with parameter values, incorrect input values and extra information from `errno` using `strerror(errno)` if necessary. For example: `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); if (f == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno)); return 1; }`